# rails: start the server with multiple port in single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, port

Is there any possible to run rails server with multiple port in a single command?.

I know the following command is help to start the server with the port number 3001

```
rails s -p 3001
```

But, I'm expecting the command like following... Need to start the server with multiple port in single line

```
rails s -p 3001..3006 
or
rails s -p 3001 3002 3003
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 or more instances of the rails server one for each port.  Your other option could be to have your firewall or router forward traffic from each of these ports to a single port on the machine.

Comment: "You can run 2 or more instances of the rails server one for each port." Yes, I'm accepted. But, I'm also need the same type process when we execute this "rails s -p 3001..3006". So, here 6 Instance with 6 Port. This is what i need.

Comment: what webserver are using for Rails server

Comment: and just to make sure I understand you correctly you need 1 process to span 6 or more ports, if so is there a reason you can't have the your firewall/router port forward to a single port